# My azure student account is not eligible to access most of the services and resources

Tags: azure, azure-storage, access-denied

My azure student account is not able to access most of the services and resource groups like microsoft Entra Id and subscriptions, storage account etc. I'm getting the exact same error message, which is very frustrating.

You don't have access to this
Your sign-in was successful, but you don't have permission to access this resource.
[image]
[image]

I also publish my web app in visual studio 2019 to azure and I also get the error of unable to create the publish profile in my local computer when I sign in my azure student account into visual studio 2019.

I expect to take the exam Az 204 and can I be possible to sit in the range of azure student account free services.

Answer (score 0):

> (Code: AccessDenied) Access is denied to the requested resource. The user might not have enough permission. (Code: AccessDenied) Try refreshing the page. Your resources aren't affected by the issue.

According to this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/30044/azure-portal-unable-to-view-resources-resource-gro) by JamesTran-MSFT:

- The above error looks like an authorization issue; you need to sign in through a new, private browser window. If the issue persists, you can try clearing your browser's cache and cookies or logging in with an incognito window.
- If restarting your session or browser does not fix the issue, you can add the IAM permissions like the [reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader) role to your subscription if you are the owner of that subscription.
- This issue may be due to your subscription being expired, your user account not being enabled, or you being locked out from your user account.

Once I add the **reader** role to the user, they can view the resource.

**Portal:**

[image]

[image]

If you need to create or update, you need the **`contributor`** role. The Reader role is only to view the resources.